# Best php/mysql date format to use for scheduling & timecard system?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date, time

I know it's been asked a different ways a thousand times, but I have yet to find an answer most people tend to agree with. It seems like everyone has their own (often completely different) idea of how to store dates in mysql.

For a scheduling & timecard system, what would be the best way to store dates & times? Date & time ranges will have to be calculated, things such as 'total time worked' in a day/week/etc will have to be calculated, etc.

Keep in mind people may be clocking in from DIFFERENT TIMEZONES, so the time would have to be offset properly to display in their local time. I can't just output a "one size fits all" timestamp.

So, with that said, what's everyone's opinion on this?

Comment: At the time a user enters a value, it must be clear for the user, which value he/she enters. For example if I live in Bangalore and enter my work time in EST Time, it would be correct, as long as it's clear that the time I enter is in EST. Create user profiles,  they then specify their timezone. Display it next to input fields so that they are aware when entering values. For comfort, make it easy to change the timezone on-the-go.

Comment: I do have a timezone offset field that I plan to utilize, I just haven't started building everything until I'm sure what time format to use.

Comment: In the database you always use UTC. The user enters in it's natural form, like current timezone. You only need to know what the current timezone of the user is. That said, your appplication needs to know how to deal with the input. As you're coding in PHP and if you really want to learn about this, I can suggest you [Derick Rethans' book: "php|architect's Guide to Date and Time Programming"](http://derickrethans.nl/phparchitects-guide-to-date-and-time-programming.html), I assume he has some slides of his talks about the topic as well on his website you can just download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a timestamp / datetime field and store the value in UTC time. Convert to the local timezone for output to the user.

That way you can easily do math on clock in / clock out times and there won't be a huge mess when trying to convert between timezones.

Comment: I setup a mysql field to automatically insert the current timestamp. When a new row is inserted, it is saving the date like 2011-10-05 19:00:33. I thought that this was going to insert the seconds since 1970.

Comment: datetime/timestamp both use the format that you listed. With timestamp you need to watch out for any TZ conversions that mysql may try to do for you. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html

Comment: Im trying to just enter the seconds since Jan 1 1970 and I can do the calculations in PHP, but it's entering a local time zone formatted timestamp..?

Comment: You can either use `strtotime()` in PHP or use the MySQL `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function when you select your data. Something like: `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp_col) AS timestamp_col FROM table`

Comment: Thank you for clarifying... because it's saved as a specific date and time in mysql, is that going to be a problem down the road if in a different timezone, etc? I thought I was supposed to save the millisecond string in the database.

Comment: As long as you save it as the UTC value of the date/time and handle any TZ conversions in your code this shouldn't be a problem. You are saving the unix timestamp version, mysql is just formatting it appropriately for storage.